# PCA - Extract variables falling below a certain threshold from the Communalities table in R

Tags: r, pca

I'm new here, and still learning how to properly use R, but I find myself in the need of some expert help. I am currently using the package `EFA.dimensions` to do my PCA. For this purpose, my script looks like this:

```
PCA(data, corkind='pearson', Nfactors=11, Ncases=NULL)
```

From the "Communalities" table which appears on the results (shown in the image below), I would like to extract the list of those variables with an **extraction communality below 0.80**. Here in the shown example there is only one variable, "ZLocomotionSocial", but I have another dataset which might end up containing many of them, so it would be great to not have to look for them one by one. If it helps, the final objective is to remove those variables from "data" and then re-run the PCA.

[Communalities table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4uNC.png)

Any suggestions on which code I can use to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform the `communalities` object in a data frame and then do some basic filtering using the `dplyr` package:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(EFA.dimensions)

communalities <-
  data_Harman %>%
  PCA(Nfactors=3, corkind = "pearson") %>%
  pluck("communalities") %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "variable")
#> 
#> Ncases must be provided when data is a correlation matrix.
#> 
#> 
#> Principal Components Analysis
#> 
#> Specified kind of correlations for this analysis: from user
#> 
#> The specified number of factors to extract = 3
#> 
#> Model Fit Coefficients:
#> 
#> RMSR = 0.046
#> 
#> GFI = 0.993
#> 
#> CAF = 0.5
#> 
#> 
#> Eigenvalues and factor proportions of variance:
#>             Eigenvalues    Proportion of Variance    Cumulative Prop. Variance
#> Factor 1           4.67                      0.58                         0.58
#> Factor 2           1.77                      0.22                         0.81
#> Factor 3           0.48                      0.06                         0.87
#> Factor 4           0.42                      0.05                         0.92
#> Factor 5           0.23                      0.03                         0.95
#> Factor 6           0.19                      0.02                         0.97
#> Factor 7           0.14                      0.02                         0.99
#> Factor 8           0.10                      0.01                         1.00
#> 
#> Unrotated PCA Loadings:
#>               Factor 1   Factor 2   Factor 3
#> Height           -0.86      -0.37      -0.07
#> Arm.span         -0.84      -0.44       0.08
#> Forearm          -0.81      -0.46       0.01
#> Leg.length       -0.84      -0.40      -0.10
#> Weight           -0.76       0.52      -0.15
#> Hips             -0.67       0.53      -0.05
#> Chest.girth      -0.62       0.58      -0.29
#> Chest.width      -0.67       0.42       0.59
#> 
#> Promax Rotation Pattern Matrix:
#>               Factor 1   Factor 2   Factor 3
#> Height           -0.92       0.10      -0.05
#> Arm.span         -0.95      -0.10       0.12
#> Forearm          -0.95      -0.07       0.02
#> Leg.length       -0.93       0.10      -0.10
#> Weight           -0.07       0.87       0.06
#> Hips              0.01       0.75       0.17
#> Chest.girth       0.06       0.99      -0.13
#> Chest.width       0.00       0.07       0.94
#> 
#> Promax Rotation Structure Matrix:
#>               Factor 1   Factor 2   Factor 3
#> Height           -0.94       0.44       0.37
#> Arm.span         -0.95       0.35       0.42
#> Forearm          -0.93       0.33       0.35
#> Leg.length       -0.93       0.42       0.32
#> Weight           -0.45       0.93       0.61
#> Hips             -0.36       0.85       0.62
#> Chest.girth      -0.30       0.89       0.44
#> Chest.width      -0.40       0.64       0.99
#> 
#> Eigenvalues and factor proportions of variance:
#>             Eigenvalues    Proportion of Variance    Cumulative Prop. Variance
#> Factor 1           3.51                      1.17                         1.17
#> Factor 2           2.33                      0.78                         1.95
#> Factor 3           0.96                      0.32                         2.27
#> 
#> Promax Rotation Factor Correlations:
#>            Factor 1   Factor 2   Factor 3
#> Factor 1       1.00      -0.41      -0.39
#> Factor 2      -0.41       1.00       0.60
#> Factor 3      -0.39       0.60       1.00
communalities
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>   variable    Communalities
#>   <chr>               <dbl>
#> 1 Height              0.882
#> 2 Arm.span            0.909
#> 3 Forearm             0.872
#> 4 Leg.length          0.871
#> 5 Weight              0.872
#> 6 Hips                0.742
#> 7 Chest.girth         0.803
#> 8 Chest.width         0.975

selected_communalities <-
  communalities %>%
  filter(Communalities < 0.8)
selected_communalities
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   variable Communalities
#>   <chr>            <dbl>
#> 1 Hips             0.742

selected_variables <- selected_communalities$variable
selected_variables
#> [1] "Hips"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much danlooo! May I ask another question, please? Now that I have the "selected_variables", do you know how I can use it with the command "remove"? I'm trying to use the following script for it, but it did not work so far: `within(data, rm(selected_variables))`

Comment: `rm` is to remove R objects from the computers' memory. I guess you just want to *filter* the rows to see the selected variables and their commonality in one data frame. I updated the answer accordingly. I suggest to read this chapter to get the basic skills: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right, I didn't exlain myself: what I want to do is to remove these selected variables (those below 0.8) from my original data, so I can re-run the PCA without them.

Comment: I actually just managed to do it with the script: `within(data, rm(list = selected_variables))`, in case it helps anybody ;-)